# Como puedo solucionar el salto de los divs a que se mantengan

Tags: html, css, style

Como puedo hacer que esos div de productos y el resto de abajo no me hagan ese salto de linea si no se mantengan en una sola linea gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: prueba con diplay:flex; al contenedor padre.

desde ahi los podras controlas en filas o columnas

te recomiendo leer [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un contenedor `flexbox` para todos los ítems que quieras colocar en línea:

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row">
  <div>Productos</div>
  <div>Vestidos de baño</div>
  <div>Accesorios</div>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo me ayudaste un monton